# Redux store reducers implement wrong interfaces

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, redux, react-redux

I created a redux store with 2 different "Slice". First, I have an appSlice:

appSlice.ts

```
import { createSlice, PayloadAction } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";
import type { RootState } from "./store";

export interface CounterState {
  value: number;
}

const initialState: CounterState = {
  value: 0,
};

export const appSlice = createSlice({
  name: "counter",
  initialState,
  reducers: {
    increment: (state) => {
      state.value += 1;
    },
    decrement: (state) => {
      state.value -= 1;
    },
    incrementByAmount: (state, action: PayloadAction<number>) => {
      state.value += action.payload;
    },
  },
});

export const { increment, decrement, incrementByAmount } = appSlice.actions;

export const selectCount = (state: RootState) => state.app.value;

export default appSlice.reducer;
```

And I have a cameraSlice.ts

```
import { createSlice, PayloadAction } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";
import type { RootState } from "./store";

export interface CameraState {
    cameraImage: string | null;
}

const initialState: CameraState = {
  cameraImage: null,
};

export const cameraSlice = createSlice({
  name: "camera",
  initialState,
  reducers: {
    setCameraImage: (state, action: PayloadAction<string>) => {
      state.cameraImage = action.payload;
    },
    resetCameraImage: (state) =>{
        state.cameraImage=null;
    }
  },
});

export const { setCameraImage, resetCameraImage } = cameraSlice.actions;

export const selectCameraImage = (state: RootState) => state.camera.cameraImage;

export default cameraSlice.reducer;
```

The error coming from this selectCameraImage, the error message: `Property 'cameraImage' does not exist on type 'CounterState'.`

Now my store looks like this:
store.ts

```
import { configureStore } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";
import appReducer from "./appSlice";
import cameraReducer from "./appSlice";

export const store = configureStore({
  reducer: {
    app: appReducer,
    camera: cameraReducer,
  },
});

export type RootState = ReturnType<typeof store.getState>;
export type AppDispatch = typeof store.dispatch;
```

hooks.ts:

```
import { TypedUseSelectorHook, useDispatch, useSelector } from "react-redux";
import type { RootState, AppDispatch } from "./store";

export const useAppDispatch = () => useDispatch<AppDispatch>();
export const useAppSelector: TypedUseSelectorHook<RootState> = useSelector;
```

How can I fix that issue? Now, the app and the camera are CounterState type, I don't know why.
If you have any idea, please let me know! Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't see a `CounterState` defined anywhere there, so maybe you just have another file flying around?
Also, if you take a look at your imports,

```
import appReducer from "./appSlice";
import cameraReducer from "./appSlice";
```

is definitely wrong.

Comment: Oh God, stupid mistake, thank you so much!:D